# UITextView in Storyboard - is there a way to append text programatically?

Tags: ios, storyboard, uitextview

I have some text in a `UITextView` that I wrote in the `storyboard`. I did that because I used colors and bold fonts there, which made it easier.
I want to add some text that is taken from a variable. Is there a way to do it programatically ? I mean to append some text to the text I initially put in the `storyboard`?

Comment: Just because I read it the second time now: _programmatically_ has nothing to with programming. ;)

Answer (score 4):

Create a reference to the textView from storyboard, then in run time

Swift

```
let textToAppend = "some text"
mytextView.text = textView.text.stringByAppendingString(textToAppend)
```

Objective C

```
mytextView.text = [mytextView.text sringByAppendingString:variableText];
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
  NSMutableAttributedString *strPrev=(NSMutableAttributedString*)txtView.attributedText;
[strPrev appendAttributedString:[[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"MynewString"]];

[txtView setAttributedText:strPrev];
```

Comment: Please test correctly, in my code if you append "some text" it is also in bolded format.

Comment: i have modified my answer, please recheck and let me know.